# Is it safe to inherit std::exception in an exported DLL?

Tags: c++, exception, dll, dllexport

I'm preparing a DLL lib whose functions / class-methods can throw exceptions. **Is it safe to throw instances of classes that inherit `std::exception` by the DLL-exported methods?**

### Background

- I've been informed that it is dangerous to export STL-class variables or functions/methods whose signatures include STL classes, since the code that may use the DLL might have different definitions/implementations of the STL classes, which may cause an undefined behavior when integrated.
- In principle, I can write an exception class that will not inherit `std::exception`, however, such kind of exception will not be caught by `catch (const std::exception &e)`, which is usually used when intended to catch any thrown exception.
- I'm trying to understand whether exporting `std::exception` will suffer from the same problem of other STL classes.

Comment: If the dll can be used with a different compiler vendor its not safe for the same reason using the standard library across dll boundaries is not safe. One way around the problem is release dll binaries for each compiler and require that the users of your software use the correct dll. With msvc it used to be not safe to use a dll across vs versions but VS 2015 to 2022 has binary compatibility.

Comment: This depends on how you are going to use the DLL.  You didn't describe how you are going to use the DLL.  So answering your question isn't possible without guessing.  Can you tell us how you are going to use your DLL?  Do you understand the ways that matter?